# Suppose that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n^{2}x^{n}$ converges exactly on [-6,6].

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Suppose that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n^{2}x^{n}$$ converges exactly on [-6,6]. Find the largest set on which you can guarantee that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^{n}$$ converges, and prove your answer.

I think the largest set is $(-\sqrt{6},\sqrt{6})$. I am not sure how to prove this answer.

Comment: This boils down to finding $(a_n)$ such that $\sum a_n^2\,6^n$ converges but, say, $\sum a_n\left(\sqrt6\right)^n$ diverges. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

The radius of convergence of the first series is

$$R=6=\frac {1}{\lim_{\infty}(a_n)^\frac 2n }$$

$$\implies $$

$$\frac {1}{\lim_{\infty}|a_n|^{\frac 1n}} $$
$$=\sqrt {6} $$
$=$ the radius of convergence of the second.

Comment: WHERE IS THE MISTAKE

Comment: How is this dealing with the convergence at $\sqrt6$ and $-\sqrt6$?